# Book: children born on a planet die at 16 unless they pay for the powder to live longer; girl is recruited by government agents

Tags: story-identification, books

I don’t remember a book I read a long time ago, that talks about a world in the future where people had to leave Earth and they find another planet where they also find a powder that permits them to live longer.

The downside is that people born on that planet are only able to live until 16 and have to take the powder after that to live longer (the powder is also exploited and you have to pay to have it).

The story is centered on a 16-year-old girl who has never studied for anything, as she didn’t want to, and is about to die when she is saved by government agents. They then recruit her to work as a sort of time keeper as we discover that the government have created a sort of history line where people can access it.

Comment: Hi there! About how long ago is "a long time ago"? Three years? Fifteen? The 50s?

Comment: Also - your first revision had both the words "power" and "powder". I'm assuming powder is the right one as it appeared once more, but could you confirm?